# Is there a way to directly access a company's SEC 10-K document using a ticker search in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

so I am trying to create a website in react that would help an investor understand company's financial standing base on SEC filing. The issue I am having is that how do I look apple 10-K or search that document instead of clicking through different page to get to that direct document when the user search's a ticker.

So far, I found a way to lookup CIK number for a ticker when a user searches for a ticker. However, I am stumped on how to get the document.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.